# Cannot GET /api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

I have a problem with my post data to the server. Not sure why i get an error for get when i changed my rout to post.

routes/feedback.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { emailFeedback } = require("../controllers/feedback");

router.post("/feedback", emailFeedback);

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

// import routes
const feedbackRoutes = require("./routes/feedback");

// app
const app = express();

// middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// routes
app.use("/api", feedbackRoutes);

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: But you don't have a `get` route defined. You only have a `post`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the usual syntax for an express post route is as follows:

```
    router.post("/feedback", function(req, res){
    //grabbing the request body
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.bodt);
    //posting the request
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

A callback function needs to be passed in and receive those request and response parameters (req, res).